# WPF - Refresh DataGrid of window1 from window2

Tags: c#, wpf

Using `Entity Framework` my `WPF MainWindow` displays data from an `SQLite` database. A button1 click in my `WPF MainWindow` opens a new window (dialog) as follows:

```
Window2 MyWindow2 = new Window2();
MyWindow2.ShowDialog();
```

A button2 click event in `Window2` performs some database changes and the newly changed data needs to be displayed in the `DataGrid` on `MainWindow`. So, I need the `DataGrid` in `MainWindow` to be refreshed when user clicks button2 of `Window2` to update data . **Question**: How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to reload main window all you need to pass updated data from window2 to main window using delegate and events or using properties. Otherwise when you launch main window some methods are called to bind data in main window call same when close window2.

```
Window2 MyWindow2 = new Window2();
MyWindow2.ShowDialog();
//Call here methods of data binding of main window.
```

Comment: I used your suggestion and it worked (thank you). Also, liked your points a) no need to reload the main window: b) When you launch main window some methods are called to bind data in main window call same when close window2.

Comment: I just noticed that although `MyWindow2.ShowDialog();` refreshes the data, it does create a new instance of the window. Since it's a parent window, the two instances of the same window are opened. User has to close one of those instances. Is there a way to not to have the two instances of the same window opened at the same time?